# Conditional logic with chained AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page which loads posts from multiple saved Instagram feeds. Feed objects look like this:

```
{'feed_type' : 'search', 'feed_term' : '#cars'}
{'feed_type' : 'profile', 'feed_term' : 'FerrariOfficial'}
```

If the feed relates to an Instagram profile rather than a hashtag, we need to first query the Instagram API for that username's ID (as Instagram doesn't allow querying by username).

There's also a form on the page to add a new feed, and I want to reuse these checks and displaying methods once a feed is added.

I have the following functions:

```
getInstagramIdFromUsername()
displayPosts()
addNewFeed()
```

Ideally this would be the main logic:

```
onLoad() {
    // for each feed...
    if (f.feed_type == "profile") {
        getInstagramIdFromUsername(f);
    }
    displayPosts(f);
}

onAddFeedFormSubmitted(f) {
    if (f.feed_type == "profile") {
        getInstagramIdFromUsername(f);
    }
    addNewFeed(f);
    displayPosts(f);
}
```

However I'm having trouble structuring my logic as all these functions are asynchronous AJAX calls. What's the best way to do this? Should I be using jQuery's [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) here?

Comment: could you please provide data in the JSON format? => is an arrow function in js... Also onLoad() must either be in a class, or it is a syntax error ( missing the *function*)

Comment: Also you dont need a deferred object, you can simply chain the ajax calls using promises etc..

Comment: Thanks - just changed to JSON format.

Comment: @Jonasw if you could show me how to do it with Promises that would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is asynchronous, you should add a callback functionality;

```
getInstagramIdFromUsername(callback)
```

callback get execute after it get the feed, so you can just go like so:

```
onLoad() {
    if (feed_type == "profile") {
        getInstagramIdFromUsername(function() {displayPosts();});
    } else { 
        displayPosts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the Object that is returned by the $.ajax function. Its a deferred object:

```
onLoad() {
// for each feed...
if (f.feed_type == "profile") {
    getInstagramIdFromUsername(f).done(function(data){
        displayPosts(f);
    });
}else{
    displayPosts(f);
}

}

onAddFeedFormSubmitted(f) {
if (f.feed_type == "profile") {
    getInstagramIdFromUsername(f).done(function(data){
    addNewFeed(f);
    displayPosts(f);
 });
}else{

}
}
```

So your getInstagramFromUsername function will look like this:

```
function getInstagramIdFromUsername(){
   return $.ajax({
       url:"api/"
    });
}
```

You can implement a more advanced behaviour with custom datatypes. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If I use .done() as you suggest, what happens to the existing done, fail and always methods I've defined?

Comment: @Seano *existing done,fail and always methods* are not existing to me, as you dont provide them in yor code...